# Google map to find current location and nearby places

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to add a Google Maps plugin in my Android app to fetch the current location of a user and show nearby hospitals. 
How to fetch the current location and nearby places? Could somebody give me a direction on it?

Comment: Please refer this link : https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-search-nearby-displaying-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-google-maps-api-v2/

Comment: Grammar correction, spelling and tag addition.

Comment: Try this link too in addition to @Akash link: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the following code you will get nearby hospitals it's working.:)

You Can change this type at your own will, e.g hospital, cafe, restaurant.... and see how it all works:

```
    public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
            LocationListener {

        private GoogleMap mMap;
        LocationManager locationManager;
        CoordinatorLayout mainCoordinatorLayout;
        String type;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
                return;
            }
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            type="hospital";

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            mainCoordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainCoordinatorLayout);
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                showLocationSettings();
            }
        }

        private void showLocationSettings() {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(mainCoordinatorLayout, "Location Error: GPS Disabled!",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Enable", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override                    public void onClick(View v) {

                            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                        }
                    });
            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
            snackbar.setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
            TextView textView = (TextView) sbView
                    .findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

            snackbar.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

            showCurrentLocation();
        }

        private void showCurrentLocation() {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
        }

        private void loadNearByPlaces(double latitude, double longitude) {


            StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl =
                    new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
            googlePlacesUrl.append("location=").append(latitude).append(",").append(longitude);
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=").append(PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=").append(type);
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
            googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + GOOGLE_BROWSER_API_KEY);

            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(googlePlacesUrl.toString(),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject result) {

                            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: Result= " + result.toString());
                            parseLocationResult(result);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: Error= " + error);
                            Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: Error= " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
        }

        private void parseLocationResult(JSONObject result) {

            String id, place_id, placeName = null, reference, icon, vicinity = null;
            double latitude, longitude;

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = result.getJSONArray("results");

                if (result.getString(STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase(OK)) {

                    mMap.clear();

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject place = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        id = place.getString(SUPERMARKET_ID);
                        place_id = place.getString(PLACE_ID);
                        if (!place.isNull(NAME)) {
                            placeName = place.getString(NAME);
                        }
                        if (!place.isNull(VICINITY)) {
                            vicinity = place.getString(VICINITY);
                        }
                        latitude = place.getJSONObject(GEOMETRY).getJSONObject(LOCATION)
                                .getDouble(LATITUDE);
                        longitude = place.getJSONObject(GEOMETRY).getJSONObject(LOCATION)
                                .getDouble(LONGITUDE);
                        reference = place.getString(REFERENCE);
                        icon = place.getString(ICON);

                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);
                        markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);

                        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), jsonArray.length() + " Supermarkets found!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (result.getString(STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase(ZERO_RESULTS)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Supermarket found in 5KM radius!!!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "parseLocationResult: Error=" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("My Location"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

            loadNearByPlaces(latitude, longitude);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }

        private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
            GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
            int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                    apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                    finish();
                }
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here is the xml file.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

its workind at my side. please add the api key and enjoy it.Hope this help:)